# Can I run PCA on a 4-tensor?

Tags: machine-learning, pca, scikit-learn

I have a dataset that is a 4D Tensor stored in a numpy array. I would like to do PCA on it, but sklearn.PCA only takes arrays with dim <= 2. I know I can reshape the array, but will that not lose information or cause PCA to fit to the wrong vectors?

Comment: Could you explain what "do PCA on" a 4D tensor is intended to accomplish?

Comment: I might be misunderstanding the point of PCA, but essentially I'd like it to cut down the 4D tensor to be whatever the principal components might be, probably a 3D tensor. I know that I could just start lopping off data, but I was hoping PCA could do it in such a way that I wouldn't lose much information. The reasoning is that I have a limited amount of data, but to train a CNN on the data, I feel that having the input be 3D images causes the network to become too complicated for the size of my data set, thus causing issues like over and underfitting.

Comment: Okay, we need to make sure we have a common understanding of what you mean by "4D tensor."  Is it an object that requires four indexes or would it be an array with four columns?  I had thought you meant the former, but in that case what would it mean to "cut it down" or "lop off data"?

Comment: It is an object that requires four indices. More or less it is a list of 3D images, but must be treated as a Tensor. Again, I could be misunderstanding PCA, but from my understanding it tries to simplify data down to principal, uncorrelated components, which is what I  would like to do with my data as well.

Comment: For many purposes--including those where PCA is frequently used--an image can be considered as a vector.  Thus, you have an array whose rows are images and columns are voxels.  This structure might or might not be useful, depending on what you're trying to accomplish.  Telling us that you want to "do PCA" isn't terribly informative: perhaps you could edit the post to describe your objectives.  Otherwise, there's a real chance most or even all of the answers you're getting will not be appropriate for your situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PCA won't work on a 4D tensor, but you could use an auto-encoder.

Note that PCA will take a 2D dataset and reduce the number of columns in it (say 100 columns to 10).

With a 4D dataset, you could use an autoencoder to either reduce it to a 4D dataset with fewer "columns" or reduce it to a 3D dataset.

Comment: @Ammastaro Honesty, depending on the dataset and what you're trying to accomplish, reshaping to 2D and doing PCA may also work.

Answer (score 6):

There are actually a few generalizations of PCA to higher-order tensors:

- The [Tucker decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tucker_decomposition) used in "[higher-order singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_singular_value_decomposition)".
- [PARAFAC aka CANDECOMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_rank_decomposition), is in some ways a special case of Tucker decompositions.
- Another, more recent variant [uses the tensor train decomposition](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.05026).

Answer (score -2):

The answer to the question in the title is *yes, you can* perform a PCA on any set of data described by a coordinate system with any number of axes. The result is a new set of axes, called principal coordinates. The PCA produces as many PC as there are original axes, but the new coordinate system as different properties, such as:

- The principal components are ranked based on how much variability
  they account for, the first PC being the axis with maximum
  variability along itself;
- by definition, all principal components are orthogonal to each other.

[Here](http://setosa.io/ev/principal-component-analysis/) is a very good interactive explanation of what PCA does and how does it work. For further reference see [here](https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat505/node/51/), [here](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441996497).

The details in the text body seem to refer to a specific program (I'm guessing Python), which make me think that this question may be more suitable for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't think that this answers the question. PCA is defined in terms of 2 axes, i.e. a matrix; the question is whether PCA can be generalized to what we could call a "generalized matrix" with 4 axes, but more commonly called a "4-tensor."

Comment: If the title question “Can I run PCA on a dataset of dimension 4?” refers to Principal Component Analysis, then my answer (in short: “yes, you can”) is correct*.
I’ve never heard that a PCA is defined in terms of 2 axes. Can you provide a reference (and a clearer definition)? The fact that PCA is often used to represent multivariate data in a 2D space is a different story; that is only one possible application of PCA.
If the question implies “Can I run PCA on a dataset of dimension 4 using a specific program?” then it should be asked more clearly and perhaps moved to Stack Overflow.

Comment: *Some references: http://setosa.io/ev/principal-component-analysis/ ; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis ; https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781441996497

Comment: I agree that the title isn't a good description of the actual question; the body and comments give more information. The references that you link to give a good explanation of exactly what I mean when I say PCA is defined in terms of 2 axes! A single element of a matrix $A$ can be written as $A_{ij}$, where $i$ and $j$ are the two axes that describe it. A single element of a 3-tensor $B$ can be written as $B_{ijk}$, which you can imagine looks like a "stack" of several matrices, creating a "volume" of numbers. A single element of a 4-tensor $M$ can be written as $M_{hijk}$.

Comment: Hi, I think I get it now. But couldn't a n-tensor be easily "repacked" as a matrix? (I could make a practical example but it'd take more than the allowed number of characters to describe it.)

Comment: I think whether or not "repacking" the elements is a core component of the question. A black and white image can be represented as a matrix; a color image has R, G and B channels in addition to width and height, so it's a 3-tensor. A "stack" of color images has a fourth axis for the number of images. If you repack the 4-tensor of images, the spatial arrangement of pixels will be disrupted. Whether or not spatial arrangement matters in OP's use-case is only something that OP could answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80990/discussion-between-marco-plebani-and-sycorax).